# What are the hottest temperatures ocean life can survive at

Tags: oceanography, temperature, climatology, hypothetical, evolution

What are the hottest average annual temperature for life in the ocean to withstand? Particularly algae
This could include life from all points in earth history.

Comment: If local environments matter on your question the answer must be searched at black somkers. There are thermophyllous organisms that can live over water fussion point 100ºC

Comment: I am thinking more about what I'm trying to ask and I think I'm asking about increased temperature which is meant to be caused by increased sunlight. I probably shouldve asked what would happen to algae and ocean life if subjected to 2-2.5 times aa much sunlight and mentioned that I was wondering about how that sunlight could increase temperature. On the other hand thats not what I'm asking and would be a different question.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. We would have to answer this for every possible depth and current - that requires a book.

Comment: I agree with JanDoggen. You have to define what do you mean with "ocean life". You mean complex ecosystems as the one we see today? Or a lonely extremophile  unicelular algae would fit the bill? If the latter, most likely @Universal_learner is right, and it would be as hot as liquid water can exist. If the former, one answer could be current temperature, as there are already some ecosystems collapsing, although it might have more to do with PH than temperature, as both are somehow linked.

Comment: It seems more broad than I intended I would think it can be limited to the photic zone when talking about depth.

Comment: And I am sure sea animals would have a limit like that of land animals due to enzymes. I would be fine with editing the question to only include algae.

Comment: i do not think this question is well formulated,the max temparature for survival is often a lot higher than the temparature where an animal can live,often the limiting factor is where can the food for the animal live.it is not very helpful to survive for a short time just to starve to death later.

Comment: For algae, the limit isn't really the survivable temperature (above which they cook to death), but the temperature at which photosynthesis no longer produces enough energy for survival.  The efficiency drops off fairly rapidly above  45-55°C.  And of course if algae die off, there goes most of the oceanic food chain.

Answer (score 0):

The previous record-holder, P. fumarii, could live at temperatures as high as 113 °C (235 °F), well above the boiling point of water. But the new microbe, for now called “Strain 121,” thrives at 121 °C and can even survive for two hours at 130 °C.